# How to fix reference in typescript

Tags: reference, typescript

I’m trying to reference a d.ts file in typescript. I am not getting any warning along the lines of "Cannot find file". If i modify the path to point to a file I know not exists, I do. So I am fairly sure that my syntax is right. But I still get "Could not find symbol" error.

Here is the reference(file CLHistory.js)
`/// <reference path="../../HistoryJS/HistoryJS.d.ts" />`

Here is the HistoryJS.d.ts file

```
interface HistoryAdapter {
    bind(element, event, callback);
    trigger(element, event);
    onDomLoad(callback);
}

interface HistoryJS {
    enabled: boolean;
    pushState(data, title, url);
    replaceState(data, title, url);
    getState();
    getHash();
        Adapter: HistoryAdapter;
    back();
    forward();
    go(X);
    log(...messages: any[]);
    debug(...messages: any[]);
}
```

Im getting "error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'HistoryJS’." where I use HistorJS(CLHistory.ts)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a manual assignment. See : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/history/history-tests.ts#L7